# Geometrical paraxial optics

Tags: optics

Why is geometrical optics treated in 2d? I actually never thought about it and calculated all the problems straightforward with the ABCD matrices. And then this question came to my mind for which I have no answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

Usually optical systems are axially symmetric, so that you only need 2 d to understand the paths of all the rays traversing the system.